# apply stylesheet to web user control

Tags: stylesheet, web-user-controls

I want to apply **`styles`** to one **`webusercontrol`**

I have tried with

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Styles/ascxStyles.css") %>" />
```

but i'm not able to apply styles to user control.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Something Like 
href="~/Styles/StyleSheet.css"
where ~/ is Root directory of the application
and add runat="server"
Or just Drag Your css On your control it will automatically create appropriate path

Comment: It is working, when i drag shtylesheet into usercontrol. thanx @vishal

Comment: this drag and drop will also work if you want to add control on any page best Of Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your ResolveUrl is wrong. you can use this in your usercontrol or in that pages which uses this usercontrol :

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Styles.css" media="screen" />
```

Comment: Create stylesheet and just drag it into your usercontrol. it will work properly

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can also use the css file
which you have added to your `MasterPage`.

So no need to add css file to Web User Control again.